# Get user permissions to folder including indirect permissions through AD and local groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory, acl

I want to check whether a given Active Directory user (specified by username and domain) has read/(write) permissions on a given folder. And this unrelated to having them granted directly by user name or indirectly by some group membership. However I've been googling like 5 hours by now to no avail.

I understand, that `Get-Acl` Cmdlet is used to read folder permissions. Most likely the user is member of some group, that indirectly grants it permissions.

So my idea was to just match the output of

```
(Get-Acl <Folder>).Access | ft
```

against the group membership of the user.

I collect the group Information using the command

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership "<Username>" | select name
```

but found out, that this features an entirely different set of group names. I assumed, that the groups outputted by `Get-Acl` are local ones, while the other ones were AD-sided groups.

I found the command `whoami /groups`, that prints all groups, but only for the currently logged in user.

After quite some additional time I figured out the command (based on .NET):

```
(New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity -ArgumentList @(,"<User@fullDomain.com>")).Claims | select Value
```

This however just prints SIDs, while

```
(Get-Acl <Folder>).Access | ft
```

displays some human friendly output like "NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller" and such.

I believe I'm pretty close, but I just can't get it to work. 
On another note: Does this really have to be that complicated?

Other solutions I found only work based on direct user permissions but do not check group permissions.

Oh and one thing: Everything has to run on PowerShell 4.0 on Windows Server 2012 R2 and the PowerShell script will be running locally. No NuGet packages or anything requiring an Internet connection are allowed.

Comment: "I just can't get it to work" - can't get what to work? (Remember, we can't see your screen.)

Comment: What you're looking for is called "effective permissions". [Related](https://activedirectorypro.com/how-to-view-ntfs-effective-permissions/). Also, possible duplicate of [Effective permissions on remote share for domain users in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27190761).